# Fork() not working to calculate last few digits of command line arguments

Tags: c, unix, fork

I' m trying to calculate the total sum of a line of command arguments entered in from the terminal. Thus far, I've gotten to the point where it will print out everything until the very last few digits. I have to make use of fork() to do all of the computation with my companion program. The main program is unable to do any computation for the final sum. I've tried to pull out the last few digits by creating a new dynamic array, but this is useless if there happens to be 100 or more single digits for example.

It will print out from the terminal after doing ./coordinator 3 4 3 2 1 4 5 4 3 2 4 3 2

**** BEGINNING OPERATIONS ****

Process ID: 5642
Calculation: Sum of 3 and 4 is 7

Process ID: 5643
Calculation: Sum of 3 and 2 is 5

Process ID: 5644
Calculation: Sum of 1 and 4 is 5

Process ID: 5645
Calculation: Sum of 5 and 4 is 9

Process ID: 5646
Calculation: Sum of 3 and 2 is 5

Process ID: 5647
Calculation: Sum of 4 and 3 is 7

Process ID: 5648
Calculation: Sum of 2 and 0 is 2

**** MIDDLE OPERATIONS ****

ProcessID 5649: 
Calculation: Sum of 7 and 5 is 12

ProcessID 5650: 
Calculation: Sum of 5 and 9 is 14

ProcessID 5651: 
Calculation: Sum of 5 and 7 is 12

ProcessID 5652: 
Calculation: Sum of 2 and 0 is 2

**** ENDING OPERATIONS ****

ProcessID 5654: 
Calculation: Sum of 12 and 14 is 26

ProcessID 5656: 
Calculation: Sum of 12 and 2 is 14

return_array[0]: 12
return_array[1 ]: 14
return_array[2]: 12
return_array[3]: 2
return_array[4]: 26
return_array[5]: 14

Things get complicated where there are a line of odd numbers, so you must add a zero at any in point the computation. So you can make the set even again, thus allowing the computation to continue.

Such as this line: ProcessID 5652: Calculation: Sum of 2 and 0 is 2

If I make the numbers more complicated(more digits at the very beginning), the part after 'ending operations' get BIGGER and thus makes it even harder to pull the very last few sums out to end up with one total sum. I'm unable to pull these digits out.

Comment: You should consider posting your code.

Comment: What prevents you from just iterating through the argv array? Homework tag maybe?

Comment: Why are you prevented from using the main process to do the calculations?  If this is homework, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are building a recursive program.  I'm not sure why you have divided the logic into beginning, middle and end operations?

I suggest you either implement this as head::tail recursion, where each invocation adds the first argument to the result of running on the remaining ones, or returns zero if it has no arguments:

```
Program -> 0
Program head,... -> head + program ...
```

OR divide and conquer, where each invocation either returns it's single argument, zero for none, or forks two sub-invocations, each with half of the remaining arguments:

```
Program -> 0
Program x -> x
Program (N args) -> Program (N+1/2 args) + Program (remaining args)
```

No complex internal data structures are required, just some light array handling:

I should point out that it's a bad idea to communicate value through exit codes, since exit codes have a very limited set of values (256) available for this use, and if your program fails for some reason it may return a surprising value.

Here's a perl version that doesn't use exit code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print@ARGV&&(shift(@ARGV)+‘$0 @ARGV‘)||0
```

While this is in perl, which not everyone can read, and perl is doing a lot of work behind the scenes for us, it demonstrates the way you can implement a recursive head::tail sum function using fork and exec.

Here's the c version that uses exit codes:

```
int forkexec(char**oldargv,char**newargv,char**endargv)
{
  if(!fork())
    execve(newargv[0]=oldargv[0],newargv,endargv[0]=0);
  int b;
  wait(&b);
  return b>>8;
}

main(int c, char** a)
{
  int b;for(b=0;b<c;b++)printf("%s ",a[b]);printf("\n");
  exit(!(c-1)?0 // empty head returns 0
             :atoi(a[1])+ // convert the head into a number
              forkexec(a,a+1,a+c)); // re-invoke on the remaining arguments
}
```

Please note that this code is NOT SAFE, and it uses undocumented features such as the `main` argument array `argv` (`a`) being NULL terminated.  However, it works, and demonstrates recursion using fork, exec and exit codes in c.  Running with the debug printf uncommented:

```
$ gcc sum.c
$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5; echo RESULT $?
./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 
./a.out 2 3 4 5 
./a.out 3 4 5 
./a.out 4 5 
./a.out 5 
./a.out 
RESULT 15
```

As you can see, I haven't used any trees or lists - I just re-invoke the program each time, moving the argument list pointer along by one.

Here's the divide-and-conquer version:

```
int forkexec(char**oldargv,char**newargv,char**endargv)
{
  if(!fork())
    execve(newargv[0]=oldargv[0],newargv,endargv[0]=0);
  int b;
  wait(&b);
  return b>>8;
}

main(int c, char** a)
{
  //int b;for(b=0;b<c;b++)printf("%s ",a[b]);printf("\n");
  exit(!(c-1)?0: // empty leaf is 0
       !(c-2)?atoi(a[1]): // leaf returns value
              forkexec(a,a,a+1+c/2)+ // Sum left half of children 
              forkexec(a,a+c/2,a+c)); // Sum right half of children
}
```

I would like to recommend that you *don't* use my code; it's ugly, unsafe and deliberately compacted to form a small example for posting here.  You should re-write using functional decomposition, error checking and comments, as well as cloning the contents of argv into new, large enough and null terminated arrays.  Also the third argument to `execve` is misleading in my example.

Uncommenting the debug printf:

```
int b;for(b=0;b<c;b++)printf("%s ",a[b]);printf("\n");
```

we get:

```
$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; echo RESULT $?
./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
./a.out 1 2 3 4 
./a.out 1 2 
./a.out 1 
./a.out 2 
./a.out 3 4 
./a.out 3 
./a.out 4 
./a.out 5 6 7 8 
./a.out 5 6 
./a.out 5 
./a.out 6 
./a.out 7 8 
./a.out 7 
./a.out 8 
RESULT 36
```

Which clearly shows the problem being split into increasingly small halves.

Comment: Thank you, now I have an idea of how to go about do this.